# If-statement in Django Template does not work

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I playing around with a simple addressbook application and I'd like to show the company of a contact in a DetailView of a contact.

In my template:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" style="width:50%;">
    {% for company in companies %}
    {% if company.name == contact.company %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ company.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ company.street }}</td>
      <td>{{ company.plz }}</td>
      <td>{{ company.city }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

My view:

```
class ContactView(DetailView):
    model = Contact
    template_name = 'contact.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Companies                                                                                                                               
        context['companies'] = Company.objects.all()
        # Return                                                                                                                                    
        return context
```

In my models:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,)
```

and

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255,)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, blank=True, null=True)
```

What is wrong with the if statement in my template?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should compare the company itself, not the name.

Change

```
{% if company.name == contact.company %}
```

to

```
{% if company == contact.company %}
```